# Error compiling subroutine which uses module defined in same fortran file

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

I am trying to compile a fortran file, timedel.f, file

This file creates the module gettimedel

```
  module gettimedel

  parameter (maxpnt=10000)
  double precision :: q(maxpnt),qen(maxpnt)
  integer :: nrestofit

  end module gettimedel
```

Which defines the two arrays, q, qen and the integer nrestofit.

Later in this fortran file, timedel.f, I have a subroutine which uses this module to get these arrays and integer

```
      subroutine fitlors(nresdum,npt,dum1,dum2,approx,reson,backgr,
 1     error,ifail)

  use gettimedel

  intent(in) nresdum,npt,dum1,dum2,approx
  intent(out) reson,backgr,error,ifail
  integer :: liw,ifail,i,lw,nresdum,npt
  parameter (liw=2000)
  double precision :: error,backgr,fvec(npt),
 1     work(14*(nresdum+1)+4*(nresdum+1)**2 +4*npt*(nresdum+1)
 2     + 3*npt + (nresdum+1)*(2*(nresdum+1)-1))
  double precision :: dum1(npt),dum2(npt),reson(nresdum*2)
  double precision :: x(nresdum*2+1),tol
  integer :: approx(nresdum),info,iw(liw)
  external fcn,lmdf1
  work=0.0D0
  x=0.0D0
  nrestofit=nresdum
  q(1:npt)=dum1
  qen(1:npt)=dum2
  do i=1,nrestofit
     x(2*i-1)=qen(approx(i))
     x(2*i)=q(approx(i))
  enddo
  tol=1.0D-03

          call lmdif1 (fcn,npt,nrestofit*2+1,x,fvec,tol,info,iw,
 *              work,lw)            
  reson=x(1:nrestofit*2)
  backgr=x((nrestofit*2)+1)
    print *,'Fitlors done.INFO=',info
  return
  end
```

This subroutine uses this module gettimedel to define the integer nrestofit and the arrays q() and qen() which are used in the module.

However when I compile this fortran file I see the error message

```
timedel.f(1): error #7001: Error in creating the compiled module file.   [GETTIMEDEL]
      module gettimedel
-------------^
timedel.f(388): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [GETTIMEDEL]
      use gettimedel
----------^
timedel.f(407): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [NRESTOFIT]
      nrestofit=nresdum
------^
timedel.f(415): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [Q]
      q(1:npt)=dum1
------^
timedel.f(415): error #6514: A substring must be of type CHARACTER.   [Q]
      q(1:npt)=dum1
------^
timedel.f(415): error #6054: A CHARACTER data type is required in this context.   [DUM1]
      q(1:npt)=dum1
---------------^
timedel.f(415): error #6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform.   [Q]
      q(1:npt)=dum1
------^
timedel.f(416): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [QEN]
      qen(1:npt)=dum2
------^
timedel.f(416): error #6514: A substring must be of type CHARACTER.   [QEN]
      qen(1:npt)=dum2
------^
timedel.f(416): error #6054: A CHARACTER data type is required in this context.   [DUM2]
      qen(1:npt)=dum2
-----------------^
timedel.f(416): error #6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform.   [QEN]
      qen(1:npt)=dum2
------^
compilation aborted for timedel.f (code 1)
make: *** [timedel.o] Error 1
```

I can fix this issue but defining the type of q, qen and nrestofit within the subroutine fitlors however I would like to fix it so that these types are defined correctly by the module gettimedel. (which I think my code should be doing).

I do not think this is an issue with INCLUDE paths as the module gettimedel is created in the same file as the subroutine.

I am using the compiler ifort.

Any help would be appreciated, please let me know if further information is required.

Thank you very much

James

(Where the function lmdif1 is called from minpack)

Comment: How does your compilation command look like?

Answer (score 0):

some suggestions (in this format as i cannot comment) you might want to try to resolve this:

1 put the subroutine fitlors into a new model (can be in same file if you like) and then use gettimedel in this model

2 try putting your subroutine behind the main (likely you already do)

4 usually i define my parameters as (maybe maxpnt is the culprit?):

```
integer, parameter :: a=1
```

5 try adding implicit none and see if the compiler output changes

Comment: 3. is nonsence, it is a fixed form file on first sight, stackoverflow just ate the spaces at the beginning of the lines.

Comment: @vladimir F true. i just noticed. my mistake -- edited to correct.